# Which Windows 2008 License should I buy to virtualize it on Vmware?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I need to install Windows 2008 Standard as a virtualized operating system.

Which license should I buy to spend less money and achieve a well working and legal installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 1 instance of **Windows 2008 Standard** in any virtual environment.

If you're running a Win2k8 standard VM on Win2k8 standard, then you only need 1 license. You don't need to buy 2 licenses, as long as you use the underlying Win2k8 standard purely for hardware virtualization.

[This document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fcab58a9-ccad-4e0a-a673-88a5ee74e2cc/windows_server_2008_virtual_tech-vl_brief-jan_09.docx) has full details.

Comment: My problem is that I see prices varying from 600 euros to 1200...
What's the difference?

Comment: Can you point me to the page where you're seeing the variation in pricing?

Comment: I think I have to buy: 
http://www.gogoprice.it/microsoft-t7502772-small-prem-2008-wsp2-14cpu-p-6380.html?from=Trovaprezzi

But there's also OEM which I think can't be virtualized, right?
Microsoft Oem-Win Svr Std08 Sp2 32Bx64 5Cl It

Comment: Pitto - The web page is in a language that I don't understand. Any chance you can point me to and English language version.

Comment: OEM versions can be virtualized. OEM versions are merely discounted versions sold in bulk to system manufacturers. There's no difference in features.

Comment: Afaik OEM versions should be "bind" to physical hardware, right?
I mean... If my server dies I have no right to move the virtual windows 2008 to another server, correct?